# How to place a logo on Top Center in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a TopPage, i will add the screenshot of it.

What I want to do is i have a logo, `logo.png` does what i want. I want to place it on `center of Top`. But I couldnt place it, when i add it in the page, other components goes to other places which i dont want.

```
<div>
  <img class="admin-logo" src="app/img/logo.png" height="45" />
</div>
```

Here is the code of this page,

```
<div class="page-top clearfix" scroll-position="scrolled" max-height="50" ng-class="{'scrolled': scrolled}">
  <a href="#/dashboard" class="al-logo clearfix"><img class="admin-logo" src="app/img/tga.png" height="65" />
  </a>
  <a href class="collapse-menu-link ion-navicon" ba-sidebar-toggle-menu></a>

  <!--   <div class="search"> -->
  <!--     <i class="ion-ios-search-strong" ng-click="startSearch()"></i> -->
  <!--     <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for..."> -->
  <!--   </div> -->
  <img class="admin-logo" src="app/img/logo.png" height="40" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; background-color: red;" />


  <div class="user-profile clearfix" style="background-color: blueviolet;">
    
    <div class="flag-icon">
      <img height="15" width="25" src="app/img/turkey.png" ng-click="changeLanguage('tr')" />
      <img height="15" width="25" src="app/img/us.png" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" />
    </div>
    <div class="al-user-profile" uib-dropdown>
      <a uib-dropdown-toggle class="profile-toggle-link">
        <span class="user-icon ion-android-person"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="top-dropdown-menu profile-dropdown" uib-dropdown-menu>
        <li><i class="dropdown-arr"></i></li>
        <li class="username-block">{{pageTop.username}}</li>
        <li style="text-align: center;">v2.250721.2</li>
        <li><a href="#/profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>{{ 'DASHBOARD_PAGETOP_PROFILE' | translate }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/changePassword"><i class="ion-android-lock"></i>{{'MENU_CHANGEPASSWORD' | translate}}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/logout" class="signout"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>{{ 'DASHBOARD_PAGETOP_LOGOUT' | translate
            }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--     <msg-center></msg-center> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this screenshot is what you are getting?

Comment: Can you please post a code that helps reproduce the issue?

Comment: No, its the only Top Part. And i just want to add a logo, Top Center @Bharat

Comment: Id like to but i dont know how. This is angular project, i dont know how to make producable code that could be done with html, js..

Comment: At least, could you give me a hint? i have `img` as logo. I can add it, but other components go to different places, its because i add in wrong place i guess.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form of CSS to align image center

```css
li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  
}
li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}
p { text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }
span { background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah.. I did it as in a div `<img class="admin-logo" src="app/img/logo.png" height="65" style="text-align: center;" `   i just was trying to figure out where to add this `div component`

Comment: So did you find it? or you still looking for information?

Comment: i still couldnt figure out where i should add that `img`,  im trying to find

Comment: You may have a header part probably a div. that might have some sections, left, middle right. From your image I can see there is hamburger icon, then logo image, then localization images and then user at the right most. So I would divide my header into 3 parts, and center part is where I would keep my img

Comment: exactly what i want is to divide  3 sections. So img will be in second part. But i dont know how this page is coded. When I look at codes i shared on here, there is outer div, and one div inside, in that div there are 2 divs.. I hope i am clear, sorry for my English. :)

Comment: now i updated the screenshot, i see the reason it just doesnt take all the space as a width... How can i solve this problem?